# how to break out foreach in concurrentHashMap

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have a Map inside another Map. I have to break out based on a condition to optimize my code.But the compiler complains of it. Is there an alternate way to get what I want

```
AtomicBoolean flag1 = new AtomicBoolean(true);
AtomicBoolean flag2 = new AtomicBoolean(true);

AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

s.getMap.forEach((k,v)->{
    v.forEach((k1,v1)-> {
        if(v1) flag2.set(false);
        else flag1.set(false);

        if (count.incrementAndGet() > 1 && ((!flag1.get()) || (!flag2.get()))) {
            break;
        }

});
```

Comment: What are you trying to do really? Your code looks like there's another, better way to handle it.

Comment: I am storing state of an object either up or down in an inner map with the context of the outer map;s key.  I want to know if all are down or all are up. Or partial (more than one is up). In case of partial I do not want to loop further and wanted to break out and thats where my condition to break out using the if loop

Comment: Why not use a for loop?

Comment: Yeah thats what I will do, thought I could use the cool foreach api

Comment: A `forEach` is not a for loop. It simply applies an operation to each of the map entries. If you want to break, use a simple loop.

Comment: If you want to stop at a certain point, you can use a filter.

Comment: Note: the fact that the collection is a ConcurrentHashMap doesn't make a difference i.e. it's not any more concurrent than a regular Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot break out of an iteration with the `forEach` method.  You *must* use the traditional for-each loop on the entry sets of the maps if you want to be able to exit the loop.